# How to access 1394 port in Ubuntu-Studio 20.04 for DV capture

Tags: ubuntu-studio, firewire, video-capture-card

Can anyone tell me how to access the 1394 Firewire port within Ubuntu-Studio? I have been trying for almost 2 weeks. None of the capturing software that come with Studio can find the 1394 port. May have to give up and go back to Windows 10 :-(

Comment: Firewire support seems to be phased out in Ubuntu Studio in particular and Ubuntu in general. You may have to install some packages manually to make your old hardware work. See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FireWire) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FireWire/DigitalVideo) for some pointers.

Comment: And how does one do that?